# IBM WebSphere ecommerce plugin development

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, websphere-commerce

Our products are widgets that are currently available on a few ecommerce platforms. They use the textual descriptions as well as the price of products to offer discounts and recommendations. One of the platforms we are on is [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/) which has an [app store](https://apps.shopify.com/) from which users can click an install button which then gives us access to the shop's data via an api.

A new client is using WebSphere Commerce V7 Feature Pack 5. My question is: is there anything analogous to the Shopify app store or are we better off writing an ad-hoc crawler to access the data of interest?

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different.  Since the integration is much tighter and you can access low level code and may impact more than just code, most companies write a white paper along with the source code (eg. Cybersource).    Also IBM offers a team of developers to make sure that you're doing it correctly along with a validation program to certify the integration (IBM Business Partner Innovation Centers).   Here's a list of the people who have gone through the formal program (you can create adhoc plugins, it's just that you won't get the marketing visability) - http://www-01.ibm.com/software/commerce/websphere-commerce/technology-partners/

Comment: So if a WebSphere ecommerce user wanted to offer it's data to a 3rd party with an open API (SOAP, REST, etc), they would have to roll their own?

Comment: No, they can use the WCS 100+ web services and REST services out of the box.  See the WCS API at http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.commerce.services.doc/refs/rwvserviceslist.htm and http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.commerce.starterstores.doc/concepts/cwvrestapi.htm.  It's just that most WCS installations don't allow remote connects out of the box and/or you need permissions.